# How to use gson to serialize classes with custom object attributes in android?

Tags: java, android, object, sharedpreferences, gson

I want to use Gson library to serialize and store an object which is of a custom class named "Battery". In the Battery class I have defined an array of a another custom object which is "Cannon". Here are my two classes:

Cannon.java:

```
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Cannon {
    private String id; // used for object storage
    private int number; // Cannon number in battery
    private ImageView icon;

    private long utmEast, utmNorth; // Used to define cannon global location
    private boolean isBase; // Defines if the cannon is base

    private double flyingTime;
    private int angle, side;

    public Cannon() {

    }

    public Cannon(String id, int number, ImageView icon, String connectionNumber){
        this.id = id;
        this.number = number;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.connectionNumber = connectionNumber;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

    public ImageView getIcon() {
        return this.icon;
    }

    public long getUtmNorth() {
        return utmNorth;
    }

    public void setUtmNorth(long utmNorth) {
        this.utmNorth = utmNorth;
    }

    public long getUtmEast() {
        return utmEast;
    }

    public void setUtmEast(long utmEast) {
        this.utmEast = utmEast;
    }

    public void setAsBase(boolean isBase) {
        this.isBase = isBase;
    }

    public boolean isBaseCannon() {
        return isBase;
    }
}
```

Battery.java:

```
public class Battery {

    private String id; // used for object storage

    private final Cannon cannons[] = new Cannon[6];

    public Battery(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public Cannon[] getCannons() {
        return cannons;
    }

    public void setCannon(Cannon cannon, int position) {
        this.getCannons()[position] = cannon;
    }

    public Cannon getCannon(String cannonId) {
        for (Cannon cn: this.getCannons()) {
            if (cn.getId() == cannonId) {
                return cn;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Cannon getCannon(int position) {
        return getCannons()[position];
    }
}
```

and here's my Preferences class which uses shared preferences to store application specific fields including battery object using Gson library.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import net.adeveloper.firecontrol.data.Battery;

/** stores the user object in SharedPreferences */
public class Preferences {
    /** This application's preferences label */
    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "net.adeveloper.firecontrol.preferences";
    /** This application's preferences */
    private static SharedPreferences settings;
    /** This application's settings editor*/
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    /** Constructor takes an android.content.Context argument*/
    private final Gson gson = new Gson();

    /**************************************************/

    private final Battery battery = new Battery(Reference.BATTERY_ID);

    /**************************************************/

    public Preferences(Context ctx){
        if(settings == null){
            settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
        }
       /*
        * Get a SharedPreferences editor instance.
        * SharedPreferences ensures that updates are atomic
        * and non-concurrent
        */
        editor = settings.edit();

        // Initialize battery
        String battery_json = gson.toJson(battery);
        // store in SharedPreferences
        String id = battery.getId(); // get storage key
        editor.putString(id, battery_json);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public Battery getBattery() {
        String battery_json = settings.getString(Reference.BATTERY_ID, "");
        Battery battery = gson.fromJson(battery_json, Battery.class);
        return battery;
    }

    //...

}
```

I use the preference object in my MainActivity to store application fields:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //...

        /********************************************************/

        prefs = new Preferences(this.getApplicationContext());

        /********************************************************/
```

However when it launches the application crashes and outputs Gson stackoverflowError:

```
02-10 16:39:03.110 13187-13187/net.adeveloper.firecontrol E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            java.lang.StackOverflowError
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:355)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.cr
```

**Update:**

I added the this code to my MainActivity after setContentView as I was using a device with an android version of 4.2.1:

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

//...

                /********************************************************/

                prefs = new Preferences(this.getApplicationContext());

                /********************************************************/
```

And now the stackoverflow exception has gone, but now another problem arose which is my Json string returned by toJson() and fromJson() methods is null and when I set my cannon object through the battery class using Preference object actually cannot access it again and it returns null:

```
Cannon cannon = new Cannon(id, number, icon, phone);
                prefs.getBattery().setCannon(cannon, position);
                if (prefs.getBattery().getCannons() == null) {
                    Log.d("Cannon", "NULL");
                } else {
                    for (Cannon cn: prefs.getBattery().getCannons()) {
                        Log.d("Cannon", cn + "");
                    }
                }
```

outputs:

```
Cannon: null
Cannon: null
Cannon: null
Cannon: null
Cannon: null
Cannon: null
```

Comment: Try with implementing Serializable interface in both the classes

Comment: And create a default constructor in Battery class as well.

Comment: I did and now it outputs a fatal exception.

Answer (score 1):

I ma not getting what you want to achieve ?? but you can 
 1. convert objec to json 
 2. save in SharedPreference and then 
 3. again can take json from preference 
 4.  and convert to java Object

Example

```
class Test
  {
     int id = 1;
     int name = "testing";
     }

class Main{
 Test t = new Test;
 String s = ConvertToJson(t);

 /* save the string in SharedPreferecne and you can get any 
   time string and convert again for eg.*/

  Test t2 =  ConvertToTest(TestJsonSring);

  public Test ConvertToTest(String json) {
    return new Gson().fromJson(json, Test.class);
    }

   public String ConvertToJson(Object object) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(object);
   }
  }
```

Comment: As you see, I've converted my battery class object to Json in Preferences class constructor and get it back through the method "getBattery".

Comment: The problem is `ImageView` of Cannon class. You can't directly convert ImageView to json String.

Comment: Correct Problem is With ImageView, I tried  with ImageView It is not working but without ImageView it is working fine.

Comment: Why on earth do we have to use only primitive datatypes in a class, as you see I have defined a custom object (array of "Cannon"s) in my battery class and I've heard it shouldn't have any problem. Why is it not the same with image view?

Comment: ImageView is containing display element and bitmap which is totally different format , If you want to store IamgeView go for file system and assign path to a string variable. GSON is specially designed for primitive data types.